# IMO 1988 Q4 Solution Verification

Tags: inequality, polynomials, solution-verification, contest-math

Show that set of real numbers $x$ which satisfy the inequality

$\sum_{k=1}^{70}\frac{k}{x-k}\geq\frac{5}{4}$

is a union of disjoint, half-open intervals, the sum of whose lengths is 1988.

My solution:

Let the function on the LHS of the inequality be $f(x)$, and consider the roots of the equation $f(x)=\frac{5}{4}$

Since $f(x)<0$ for $x<1$, any roots of this equation must occur with $x\geq 1$.

Now $f(x)$ has 70 discontinuities, namely at $x=1,2..,70$. Also, its first derivative is negative for all points at which it is defined, and it is clear that its range is infinite in both directions between any two of its discontinuities. Therefore, by IVT, it must have a root between each pair of discontinuities.

Furthermore, since $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$, it must have a single root at some value of $x>70$ (only one because it is strictly decreasing).

We see from this that the required subset is indeed a disjoint union of half-open intervals.

Now multiplying through the equation by

$\prod_{k=1}^{70} (x-k)$ and rearranging leads to a degree 70 polynomial in $x$ with leading coefficient $\frac{5}{4}$, and sum of roots (by Vieta's formula) being the 70th triangular number with a factor of $\frac{\frac{5}{4}+1}{\frac{5}{4}}=\frac{9}{5}$

which gives 4473

Now to get the sum of the required lengths from here, we simply subtract the 70th triangular number, i.e. the overcounted intervals before each discontinuity.

Thus, 4473 - 2485 = 1988.

QED

I'm wondering if this would get full credit, and welcome any suggestions for improvement of substance or style. Thanks.

Comment: Looks impressive to me at first and second glance at least. But the question--'would this get full credit and how to improve style'--does not seem to be fully about math per se, it seems to me to be as much about how judges grade contest math. I suppose my question is, where is there doubt in your answer?

Comment: What is "the sum of the 70th triangular number"?

Comment: Thanks both. I don't have any *particular* doubts, but it's rare that I manage to write involved proofs without missing something or other, so it's reassuring to have another set of eyes.

Comment: If your concern is earning full credit, that's something you'd have to ask a judge grading contest math questions. There's a lot of nuance in writing proofs, and people grade differently. I tend to skip some steps in my proofs. Some teachers would mark me down for it and others wouldn't.

Comment: Note that IMO frowns on any calculus solution, which means you have to rigorously prove the statements. To that end, simply saying "the first derivative is negative" isn't sufficient without further justification, and this certainly will not score 7, and might even be a $0^+$ solution (which would be a waste). $\quad$ Note that one could get around the negative first derivative by using just the other machinery that you already have, namely showing that there are at least 70 real roots via IVT, and that there are at most 70 real roots via the polynomial.